# Graphing Facebook Page "Likes" Over Time

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, analytics, graphing

I'm having trouble finding resources for graphing the total number of likes on Facebook pages I admin.

Facebook Insights show new likes/unlikes/etc, but what I'm looking for is a way to see how many fans I have now versus, say, a month ago, and a month before that, etc etc etc, like you can with Google Analytics.

I think I'm having trouble finding resources mostly because when searching any variation of "graph facebook likes", mostly what comes up is information on the Open Graph API.

Any ideas/resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `page_fans` [insight](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/), which gives you the total number of likes at any given time for your page. You should be able to go back and get data for a couple months at least.